# What is the the function $f(x)$ has the property $\sum_{n=1}^x f(x^n)=x^2$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, summation, exponentiation

What is the the function $f(z)$ has the property $\sum_{n=0}^z f(z^n)=z^2$ when $z$ is a natural number bigger than $0$, and the function $f(z)$ is differentiable everywhere.
$$f(1)+f(1)=1$$
$$f(1)+f(2)+f(4)=4$$
$$f(1)+f(3)+f(9)+f(27)=9$$
$$\dots$$
$$f(1)+f(z)+f(z^2)+f(z^3)+\dots+f(z^z)=z^2$$
I've found that $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ but the others I can't find a value to.

Comment: You are starting the summation at $1$ in the title, but $0$ in the body of your question.

Comment: GIven any $g  : \Bbb{N})_{>0} \to \Bbb{N}_{>0}$, you can extend $f$ to a differentiable function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$. So I don't believe this problem has a unique solution. Are you just being asked to find **a** function with these properties?

Comment: PS: please ignore the spurious right bracket after the first $\Bbb{N}$ above.

Comment: If you can code, you could try finding deg-n polynomial solutions to the first $n+1$ equations and see if perhaps the solutions converge to something nice.

Comment: @JairTaylor I don't know how to code yet. I'm planning to learn next school year. If you could show me how to do this I would be greatfull.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes I think so